# MySQL: Display duplicates matching two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing many columns.
What I'm trying to do is find a way I can display duplicates.

My table is info, and whilst it contains many columns, the ones I'm interested in is 'id' and 'shipping_date'. Whilst both shipping_date and id on their own may appear many times, they must not appear more than once together.
For instance

```
id       shipping_date
--       -------------
C123     2013-01-31
C123     2012-12-19
```

is perfectly fine, but if 'c123' and '2013-01-31' together were to appear more than once, I would like it display like above.

I'm at a loss and I'm quite a newbie.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
select id, shipping_date from T group by id, shipping_date having count(*) > 1;
```

EDIT: this allows you to find which records are duplicated, not to show duplicated records only once (if that's what you meant).

Comment: Considering this one displays everything perfectly, this one has solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question this is my Possible answer of your question.

```
select id, shipping_date from tablename group by id, shipping_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISTINCT keyword:

```
select distinct id, shipping_date from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, shipping_date from Table group by id,shipping_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, shipping_date from table ORDER BY id,shipping_date
```

The above will show all the duplicates, no grouping them out using distinct filter.